# How can I know if HDCP is supported in my Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, video, hdcp

I'm trying to watch Amazon Prime Video on my Arch Linux, but it forces the video quality to SD.

With Amazon support I was informed that this happens in cases where there's no HDCP supported.

I'm pretty sure this is not a hardware problem, because Prime Video works just fine in Windows 10.

Where can I find what kind of HDCP is supported on Linux, and with which hardware/drivers?

Are there any browser plugins that could help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us which hardware, drivers, and distro you're using.  It may be that there isn't a standard way to query this information and whatever information someone gave you would depend on those factors.

Comment: Do you have a `mei_hdcp` driver?   See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/mei/hdcp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like HDCP is currently not supported in Chromium on Linux: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1064949

It appears to be the same for Firefox on Linux (because of Widevine CDM): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1625155

In the Firefox issue, there is a comment explaining how to make the HDCP test tool https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/hdcp-detection/ work with Firefox. We need to set `media.eme.hdcp-policy-check.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`.

Answer (score 3):

Please note it doesn't work for me yet, but below my steps so far hoping it helps someone. I tried it with X11 instead of Wayland.
Also: You haven't specified your hardware, my answer might only help if you have intel graphics.

Check if HDCP is working: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/hdcp-detection/

The kernel module mei_hdcp supports intel graphics and i915, see: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/mei/hdcp.html)

> The mei_hdcp driver acts as a translation layer between HDCP 2.2
> protocol implementer (I915) and ME FW by translating HDCP2.2
> negotiation messages to ME FW command payloads and vice versa.

You can get the info about your graphics card with lspci. In my case:

```
lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics 640 (rev 06)
lspci -s 00:02.0 -vv | grep -i module
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Ensure you have mei_hdcp module loaded:

```
lsmod | grep hdcp
mei_hdcp               24576  0
mei                   135168  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
```

Verify we use X11 and not wayland:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Set property for hdcp with xrandr for the connected screen(s) and verify:

```
xrandr --verbose | grep -wi connected
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm

xrandr --output "DP-1" --set "Content Protection" "Enabled"
xrandr --output "DP-1" --set "HDCP Content Type" "HDCP Type1"

xrandr --verbose | grep -iE "hdcp|content protection|(DP|HDMI)-|desire"
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type1 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Enabled 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
```

To have those properties set persistently, one way is to create a file with this content:

```
cat /etc/X11/Xsession.d/96_enable_hdcp 
xrandr --output "DP-1" --set "Content Protection" "Enabled"
xrandr --output "DP-1" --set "HDCP Content Type" "HDCP Type1"
```

You probably also need the intel hdcp service: https://github.com/intel/hdcp

> The Intel(R) unified HDCP (High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection) is a user space implementation to prevent copying of digital audio & video content across digital display interfaces. It provides Linux user space implementation to enable the HDCP1.4 and HDCP2.2 protection for external digital display interfaces (HDMI/DP).

For ubuntu intel-hdcp is available as a package, I don't know if you need to build it manually for Arch Linux.

Comment: It looks like the test tool https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/hdcp-detection/ will only work in Chrome / Chromium. Is there a way to test with Firefox, for example with a publicly available DRM video that only works with HDCP?
The GitHub readme of intel-hdcp now says it is discontinued. It also says HDCP is for "external" interfaces but it fails on the internal monitor of a laptop too.
You may need to check that Intel Management Engine is enabled since it seems used for HDCP:
https://www.phoronix.com/news/HDCP-2.2-For-i915-DRM
https://www.phoronix.com/news/HDCP-2.2-Intel-Linux-Driver